# Implantações híbridas com PHP Laravel MySQL + MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com `PHP Laravel` + `MongoDB`.

A parte de login e senha vai ser modelado usando `MySQL` e utilizarei `MongoDB` para fazer um *quiz*.
Estava pensando em montar um `Schema` em `MongoDB` desse tipo:

```
var quiz = [{

    user_id: 1, //Auth::id() | O id do user vai vir do Auth do php laravel
    name: "Quiz 1",
    question: [{
        title: 'question1',
        type: 'radio',
        elements: ['radio1', 'radio2', 'radio3', 'radio4'],
        correct: ['radio1'],
        resposta: ['radio3'] //errou
    },{
        title: 'question 2',
        type: 'checkbox',
        elements: ['checkbox1', 'checkbox2', 'checkbox3', 'checkbox4'],
        correct: ['checkbox1', 'checkbox2'],
        resposta: ['checkbox1','checkbox2'] //acertou
    }]
}];
```

É comumente, nos projetos, fazer uma implantação híbrida de dois bancos?

Comment: Eu faria tudo no MySQL, mas, nada impede tal processo. Se você não tem tanta conhecimento em MongoDB não use então ...

Comment: Qual e o seu motivo de usar MongoDB em vez de MySQL?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues acho que é mais fácil fazer tudo em um Schema só do que criar várias tabelas, fazer os foreign keys e posteriormente os joins.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta para a tua pergunta final é: depende. Se você quer fazer uma implementação híbrida, sem problemas, pense com cuidado nas justificativas para fazer isso (ou para não fazer). Considerações/perguntas que me ocorrem para ajudar a decidir:

- Você já tem os usuários no MySQL? É possível migrar eles para o MongoDB se for o caso?
- Quer aproveitar a integridade referencial (joins) que o MySQL já te oferece?
- Quer aproveitar a flexibilidade de alteração do schema no MongoDB? (lembre do limite do tamanho do documento de 16MB)
- Se você usar dois bancos vai precisar gerenciar dois bancos! dois backups, dois processos, duas otimizações de consulta...
- Teu sistema pode crescer para muitos usuários/tamanho base/tráfego que justifique a escalabilidade do MongoDB?
- Como o comentário do @Virgilio Novic, você tem experiência com a utilização/admin no MongoDB? Quem sabe quer usar o projeto justamente para adquirir a experiência.